# R - Find the chance of each subset in a given universe

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let me start with an easy example of my problem.

Assume a universe of 10 people, where 1 person owns product A and 2 persons own product B
U=10, A=1, B=2

Now I want to find the chances that:
1) a person owns no products                 ==> (1 - 1/10) * (1 - 2/10) = 0.72
2) a person owns at least 1 product          ==> 1 - ((1 - 1/10) * (1 - 2/10)) = 0.28
3) a person owns 2 products                  ==> (1/10) * (2/10) = 0.02

However, I would like to have a general algorithm that sorts all these options out if there are *n* products.

Input is given as follows
`U <- 10

products <- c('A','B')

owned_by <- c(1, 2)

df <- data.frame(products, owned_by)`

Comment: I'd recommend you pick up an introduction to statistics book and get yourself up-to-speed in how to do this. Once you have it clear how the it works in theory, you can start translating it to R. Before you reach that stage, StackOverflow is not the place to ask this as it revolves around programming questions. You could try and cut the question down to just the statistical theory, and get it transferred to CrossValidated, the SE site for statistics.

Comment: how are `n` products distributed across different people?

Comment: @Paul, thanks for your comment. Perhaps I didn't make the right impression. I had my fair share of calculus and statistics during my study and Eindhoven University of Technology. So I do understand the math behind the problem, however I have less experience in writing these algoritms for computers.

Comment: @e4e5f4; by _n_ products I meant extra products, so product C, D,.., et cetera in case of my example.

Comment: @slo0t, I got that, but do we assume that 3 persons own C and so on?

Comment: I'm with @PaulHiemstra here: you know the formula(s), so grab one of the online "introduction to R Language" pages or manuals, and learn to write a function which takes as arguments Universe_Size, Number_People, and Max_Ownership (or the equivalent), and calculates the desired distributions.

Comment: @e4e5f4 that is given by a data frame, something like   `products <- c('A','B','C')  owned_by <- c(1, 2, 5)
df <- data.frame(products, owned_by)`  **sorry for the formatting, not getting the hang it**

Comment: That is exactly what we are asking for. Now, most of the input is clear. Probably another input would be `U` which should satisfy `U >= max(df$owned_by)`. You can update the question with these details along with sample R code (whatever you've entered in comments)

Comment: now lets fix the output. what do you expect in the general case? array of probabilities `p0`,`p1`,...,`pn`, where `pk` is probability that a person owns atleast `k` products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a closed form solution would involve too many terms and become overly complex. So this problem looks like a perfect candidate for Monte Carlo method.

```
set.seed(1984)

U <- 10
products <- c('A','B')
owned_by <- c(1,2) 
df <- data.frame(products, owned_by)
p = rep(0, nrow(df)+1)
num.runs = 1000

for(n in 1:num.runs)
{
  x=c()  ## list of people who own a product
  for (i in 1:nrow(df))
    x = c(x, sample(1:U, df$owned_by[i]))

  ## get the number of people who own 0, 1, 2...products
  p[1] = p[1] + (sum(hist(x,breaks=0:U,plot=F)$counts == 0) / U)
  for(i in 1:nrow(df))
    p[i+1] = p[i+1] + (sum(hist(x,breaks=0:U,plot=F)$counts >= i) / U)
}

p = p / num.runs ## average over all runs
p

## 0.7197 0.2803 0.0197
```

Comment: that's indeed what I was looking for! Thank you very much! The output is fine like this for now :)

Comment: I thought the code needed some more comments/explanation. I am glad that you found it useful.

Comment: Well, yes I'd appreciate if you could explain how the loop works. I understand the sampling part, but not how you store the results and use these in the end.

Comment: if you are familiar with monte carlo methods, the experiment is repeated over and over and avg is taken. thats the outer loop.

Comment: now the experiment - in the 1st inner loop, generate list of people who own some product and append for all products. This can have repeated values which implies that person owns more than one product.

Comment: in the next inner loop, check how many people own 0, 1, 2...products. Divide this number of people by total number of people in `U` to get probabilities.